# Formatting a number as a monetary value including separators

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need some help with a sql transformation. This part of query that I have been provided with:

```
'$' + replace(cast((CAST(p.Price1 AS decimal(10,2)) * cast(isnull(p.Multiplier,1) as decimal(10,2))) as varchar), '.0000', '')
```

Basically, it ends up being a varchar that looks like this: `$26980`

I need to insert a comma at the thousand and million mark (if applicable). So in this instance, `$26,980`

What's the easiest way to do that without having to rewrite the whole thing?

Comment: why do you want to perform this on the server side?  It would be much easier to perform this formatting in your application.

Comment: Stuff http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx

Comment: You'll have to re-write it anyway if (when?) you have to support a currency in Europe or Asia, where the formatting rules are completely different. As bluefeet suggested, it would be better to do this in your client application where you may simply be able to use an existing localization function instead of doing it yourself (C# formatting can [do this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.100).aspx), for example).

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not the primary developer on this, and I don't have any access to the application, just the sql that feeds it.... let me ask it this way, is doing it via sql even possible? This conversion for currency is US only anyway, so international rules aren't important. If not, I can shrug my shoulders at them but would like to at least attempt to help.

Comment: Offer help by suggesting this is a bad idea to do in sql. I can't imagine formating this field is such a major requirement that it can't wait to be done the right way.

Comment: Jeff O - I agree, believe me. However I don't make my living by offering help and this client has never been the listening type. Just trying to big-hammer-approach fix it for them so they get off my back, or walk away from it. If I had access to the code, I would be doing it app side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it on the client side.  Having said that, this example should show you the way.

```
with p(price1, multiplier) as (select 1234.5, 10)
select '$' + replace(cast((CAST(p.Price1 AS decimal(10,2)) * cast(isnull(p.Multiplier,1) as decimal(10,2))) as varchar), '.0000', ''),
       '$' + parsename(convert(varchar,cast(p.price1*isnull(p.Multiplier,1) as money),1),2)
from p
```

The key is in the last expression

```
'$' + parsename(convert(varchar,cast(p.price1*isnull(p.Multiplier,1) as money),1),2)
```

Note: if `p.price1` is of a higher precision than decimal(10,2), then you may have to cast it in the expression as well to produce a faithful translation since the original `CAST(p.Priced1 as decimal(10,2))` will be performing rounding.

Answer (score 1):

If you really must do it in TSQL you can use `CONVERT()`, but this sort of thing really doesn't belong in the database:

```
declare @m money = 12345678
-- with decimal places
select '$' + convert(varchar, @m, 1)
-- without decimal places
select '$' + replace(convert(varchar, @m, 1), '.00', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could turn this into a function, it only goes 50 characters back.

```
DECLARE @input VARCHAR(50)
SELECT @input = '123123123.00'
SELECT @input = CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('.', @input) > offset +1
                      THEN STUFF(@input, CHARINDEX('.', @input) - offset, 0, ',') 
                      ELSE @input END
FROM (SELECT 3 offset UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 12 UNION SELECT 18 UNION SELECT 25 UNION SELECT 33 UNION SELECT 42) b
PRINT @input
```

The offset grows by +1 for each position, because it's assuming you've already inserted the commas for the previous positions.